# Request provider in Nestjs, I cannot import REQUEST object

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nodes, nestjs

I am trying to implement a functionality with some request providers, I am following this example in the doc https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#request-provider

```
import { Injectable, Scope, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class CatsService {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {}
}
```

However, I cannot import the REQUEST object. It seems like it does not exist in the core of library

Does anyone know where is it?

[image: Error import REQUEST]

These are my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.5",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.5",
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you make sure that you have the correct dependencies installed by clearing `node_modules` and reinstalling with `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, I am completely sure. Anyway I have fount it at "import { REQUEST } from "@nestjs/core/router";" and is working

Comment: It should also work with `@nestjs/core`. Might be a problem with your IDE setup!? Or does `ts-node` also complain?

Comment: Have no idea, but I look at the source code and I found it there so I put just in case is a bug, mistake or whatever that it can happen to anyone...Thx anyway

Comment: Ok, glad it's working for you now. :-)